# How can I solve this issue?? java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 13 21:40:42 EEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
 
 **DataBaseTest.Instructor cannot be cast to DataBaseTest.Instructor**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import DataBaseTest.Instructor;

    @RestController
    public class TestWebService {

        @Autowired
        private  SessionFactory sessionFactory ;

        @GetMapping(path="/user")
        public Instructor getUser(){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Instructor instructor = (Instructor) session.get(Instructor.class,1);
            System.out.println(instructor);
            return instructor;
        }
```

----------------------------class Instructor------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor")
public class Instructor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id ;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName ;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName ;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email ;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
    InstructorDetails instructorDetails ;

    public Instructor(){

    }

    public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public InstructorDetails getInstructorDetails() {
        return instructorDetails;
    }

    public void setInstructorDetails(InstructorDetails instructorDetails) {
        this.instructorDetails = instructorDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instructor [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
                + ", instructorDetails=" + instructorDetails + "]";
    }


}
```

----------------------------class Instructor Details ------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name="instructor_detail")
public class InstructorDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id ;

    @Column(name="youtube_channel")
    private String youtubeChanel ;

    @Column(name="hobby")
    private String hobby ;

    public InstructorDetails(){

    }

    public InstructorDetails(String youtubeChanel, String hobby) {
        super();
        this.youtubeChanel = youtubeChanel;
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getYoutubeChanel() {
        return youtubeChanel;
    }

    public void setYoutubeChanel(String youtubeChanel) {
        this.youtubeChanel = youtubeChanel;
    }

    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InstructorDetails [id=" + id + ", youtubeChanel=" + youtubeChanel + ", hobby=" + hobby + "]";
    }



}
```

---------------------------Application ----------------

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg2.xml").
                addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class).addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetails.class).
                buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

-----------------------------hibernate.cfg2.xml------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb-01-one-to-one-uni?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

```
2018-08-14 11:27:48.429  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af5c7f54] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-14 11:27:49.520  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-14 11:27:49.559  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.560  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.10
2018-08-14 11:27:49.580  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;%M2_HOME%\bin;E:\Department\Java\gradle-4.7\bin;D:\;E:\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin ;C:\Users\Mohammed Mars\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\eclipse;;.]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.776  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-14 11:27:49.776  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4625 ms
2018-08-14 11:27:49.858  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.862  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet webServlet mapped to [/h2-console/*]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.868  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.869  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.869  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-14 11:27:49.869  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-14 11:27:50.295  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.3.Final}
2018-08-14 11:27:50.300  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-08-14 11:27:50.619  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2018-08-14 11:27:50.818  WARN 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2018-08-14 11:27:50.821  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb-01-one-to-one-uni?useSSL=false]
2018-08-14 11:27:50.822  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=hbstudent, password=****}
2018-08-14 11:27:50.822  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2018-08-14 11:27:50.827  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
2018-08-14 11:27:51.099  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2018-08-14 11:27:52.413  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService  'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-08-14 11:27:52.964  WARN 6924 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-08-14 11:27:53.456  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-08-14 11:27:53.816  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-08-14 11:27:54.228  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-08-14 11:27:54.719  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-14 11:27:54.737  INFO 6924 --- [  restartedMain] c.Q.mars.E3lnle_Project.V3.Application   : Started Application in 10.557 seconds (JVM running for 11.825)
2018-08-14 11:28:07.217  INFO 6924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-14 11:28:07.217  INFO 6924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-08-14 11:28:07.253  INFO 6924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 36 ms
Hibernate: select instructor0_.id as id1_0_0_, instructor0_.email as email2_0_0_, instructor0_.first_name as first_na3_0_0_, instructor0_.instructor_detail_id as instruct5_0_0_, instructor0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_0_, instructor1_.id as id1_1_1_, instructor1_.hobby as hobby2_1_1_, instructor1_.youtube_channel as youtube_3_1_1_ from instructor instructor0_ left outer join instructor_detail instructor1_ on instructor0_.instructor_detail_id=instructor1_.id where instructor0_.id=?
2018-08-14 11:28:07.919 ERROR 6924 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: DataBaseTest.Instructor cannot be cast to DataBaseTest.Instructor] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: DataBaseTest.Instructor cannot be cast to DataBaseTest.Instructor
    at com.Quraan.mars.E3lnle_Project.V3.webService.TestWebService.getUser(TestWebService.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:799) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1012) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:904) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:889) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:112) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.10.jar:9.0.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: are you sure the message is "cannot cast X to X" (i.e. identical class names, not actually X)? Because that makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I copied the error as it is :/

Comment: when i use MainClass for testing and with the same code the sessionFactory returns Instructor  object correctly !!

Comment: check your imports of those classes, this looks like 2 different classes with same name as mentioned by @zapl

Comment: DataBaseTest.Instructor cannot be cast to DataBaseTest.Instructor 
package name  is "DataBaseTest"  so is the same class

Comment: "cannot cast X to X" can happen, if the same class got loaded via different classloaders. If this is happening in your application within Tomcat, can you provide details, how are your instances created?

Comment: return an instance of the class from the database directly, look at the first code section in question

When I use the same code in the main function, it returns a correct instance and does not make the same error

Comment: can you post the full stack trace? and also `DataBaseTest` class and where you have used something like `DataBaseTest.Instructor`?

Comment: I added it (the full stack trace)  ,, DataBaseTest is a package not a class

Comment: @MohammedMarsAlQura'an Try removing the cast `(Instructor)` from `Instructor instructor = (Instructor) session.get(Instructor.class,1);`. If it doesn't work, please add the import statements in `TestWebService.java` above.

Comment: the same thing ,, it doesn't work ,, i added import statements

Comment: Try to isolate the error... Having the whole code dumped like that is not at all useful for us.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation I can think of is that it's a classloader leak as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184448/1039555.

See the comments in that answer:-

> @Musa YUVACI - ClassLoader leaks of this form are often due to
> references being held in server-scope ClassLoader (either bugs in the
> app server or developers adding libraries outside WARs/EARs.) –
> McDowell May 31 '11 at 9:08
>
> @McDowel-Thanks for reply, it works now.
> Problem was occured by adding libraries outside WARs. So after
> removing libraries from the glassfish server, it works. – Musa YUVACI
> May 31 '11 at 13:35